# From new to old Api

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

```py
@api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        for deferr in self:
            if deferr.invoice_id.state != 'draft':
                raise UserError('ERROR')
return super(account_deferred_income_charges, self).unlink()
```

I want to write the same method but with old api. how can I do this?

```py
def unlink(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    def_line_obj = self.pool.get('account.deferred.income.charges.')

return super(account_deferred_income_charges, self).unlink(
            cr, uid, ids, context=context
        )
```

Comment: can u use debug compiler approach ? It will be extremely easy for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write like the following:

```py
from openerp import osv
from openerp.tools.translate import _

def unlink(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for item in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if item.invoice_id.state != 'draft':
           raise osv.except_osv(_('User Error!'),_('Error Text'))

    return super(account_deferred_income_charges, self).unlink(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```